# More information about GEE dataset needed

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, ndvi

I have a rather basic question, in relation to the MCD43A4 006 NDVI dataset in GEE. 
I am aware of the methods used for the generation of the BRDF MODIS dataset, but I would like to know more details about the NDVI product. 
Does this products in GEE include only high quality observations? How can I check its specifications (e.g. quality, method of generation)
in GEE? The only information that I see in GEE is the following :

```
 The Normalized Difference Vegetation Index is
generated from the Near-IR and Red bands of each scene as (NIR - Red) /
(NIR + Red), and ranges in value from -1.0 to 1.0. This product is generated from the MODIS/006/MCD43A4 surface reflectance composites.
```

Comment: I am also interested in this dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is computed directly from the MCD43A4 imagery and clamped to [-1, 1].  That's it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It is unclear though what is its quality. I assume that the best way to find out is to calculate NDVI directly from the MCD43A4 collection and choose the good quality bands. I was really wondering though, if I can find more infos about it. Whoever generated this dataset should provide more information (e.g. how did they use the quality bands?).

Comment: You can do a join to get quality data as described [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-earth-engine-developers/QbOwKgFKCAA/UCXSNVLAAAAJ).